# React native: Sectionalist button scroll to up

Tags: react-native, scroll

I am learning React native app. I found one demo app from open source app about FlatList where user can click the go down of the screen as well as go up of the screen. I would like implement same logic in `SectionList`, According to React native documentation, FlatList and SectionList has almost same props. But when I am try implementing the scroll down and up button logic  SectionList, it does not work. It throws me error. Here is the [snack-bar](https://snack.expo.dev/embedded/@aboutreact/react-native-scroll-up-or-down-the-listview-on-the-click-of-button-?iframeId=lec6tn7bd&preview=true&platform=ios&theme=dark) they used FlatList Scroll down and scroll up logic.

**Here is my failed attempt on `SectionList` and [Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@alakdam/sectionlist)**

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  SectionList,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from "react-native";

const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Main dishes",
    data: ["Pizza", "Burger", "Risotto"],
  },
  {
    title: "Sides",
    data: ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Fried Shrimps"],
  },
  {
    title: "Drinks",
    data: ["Water", "Coke", "Beer"],
  },
  {
    title: "Desserts",
    data: ["Cheese Cake", "Isse Cream"],
  },
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  const listRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [contentVerticalOffset, setContentVerticalOffset] = React.useState(0);

  const CONTENT_OFFSET_THRESHOLD = 300;

  const upButtonHandler = () => {
    //OnCLick of Up button we scrolled the list to top
    listRef.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0, animated: true });
  };

  const downButtonHandler = () => {
    //OnCLick of down button we scrolled the list to bottom
    listRef.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <SectionList
        sections={DATA}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
        renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
          <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
        )}
        onScroll={(event) => {
          setContentVerticalOffset(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
        }}
        ref={listRef}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.5}
        onPress={downButtonHandler}
        style={styles.downButtonStyle}
      >
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/arrow_down.png",
          }}
          style={styles.downButtonImageStyle}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.5}
        onPress={upButtonHandler}
        style={styles.upButtonStyle}
      >
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/arrow_up.png",
          }}
          style={styles.upButtonImageStyle}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: "#f9c2ff",
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 32,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
  },
  upButtonStyle: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    right: 30,
    bottom: 70,
  },
  upButtonImageStyle: {
    resizeMode: "contain",
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  },
  downButtonStyle: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    right: 30,
    top: 70,
  },
  downButtonImageStyle: {
    resizeMode: "contain",
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using refs the ref is an object , where the value you want to access is within the current property. Also, SectionList have the `scrollToLoaction` method instead of the scrollToEnd because each section have items of their own.

[Here's](https://snack.expo.dev/09NRcrZOY) what I've put together. While the the buttons works on android and ios, on the web they wont position absolute nor will the buttons work:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  SectionList,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  useWindowDimensions,
} from 'react-native';

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const TouchableButton = ({ style, onPress, imgSrc }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={onPress} style={style}>
      <Image
        source={{
          uri: imgSrc,
        }}
        style={styles.downButtonImageStyle}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

// made list longer
const DATA = [
  {
    title: 'Main dishes',
    data: ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Risotto', 'Steak', 'Spaghetti'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Sides',
    data: ['French Fries', 'Onion Rings', 'Fried Shrimps', 'Mac and Cheese'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Drinks',
    data: ['Water', 'Coke', 'Beer', 'Lemonade'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Desserts',
    data: ['Cheese Cake', 'Ice Cream', 'Chocolate Cake'],
  },
];
const imgSize = 36;
const App = () => {
  const listRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [contentVerticalOffset, setContentVerticalOffset] = React.useState(0);
  // use view layout to position the buttons absolutely
  const [viewLayout, setViewLayout] = React.useState({});
  const CONTENT_OFFSET_THRESHOLD = 300;

  const upButtonHandler = () => {
    //OnCLick of Up button we scrolled the list to top
    console.log(`Scrolling to section:0 and index:0`);
    if (!listRef.current.scrollToLocation) console.log('no scrollToLocation');
    listRef.current.scrollToLocation?.({
      itemIndex: 0,
      sectionIndex: 0,
      animated: true,
    });
  };

  const downButtonHandler = () => {
    //OnCLick of down button we scrolled the list to bottom
    const sectionIndex = DATA.length - 1;
    const itemIndex = DATA[sectionIndex].data.length - 1;
    console.log(`Scrolling to section:${sectionIndex} and index:${itemIndex}`);
    if (!listRef.current.scrollToLocation) console.log('no scrollToLocation');
    listRef.current.scrollToLocation?.({
      itemIndex,
      sectionIndex,
      animated: true,
    });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={styles.container}
      onLayout={(e) => setViewLayout(e.nativeEvent.layout)}>
      <TouchableButton
        onPress={downButtonHandler}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          zIndex: 2,
          left: viewLayout.width - viewLayout.x - imgSize,
          top: viewLayout.y + (StatusBar.currentHeight || 40),
        }}
        imgSrc="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/arrow_down.png"
      />
      <TouchableButton
        onPress={upButtonHandler}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          zIndex: 2,
          left: viewLayout.width - viewLayout.x - imgSize,
          top: viewLayout.height - 20 - imgSize,
        }}
        imgSrc="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/arrow_up.png"
      />
      <SectionList
        sections={DATA}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
        renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
          <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
        )}
        onScroll={(event) => {
          setContentVerticalOffset(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
        }}
        ref={listRef}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 32,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
  },

  downButtonImageStyle: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    width: imgSize,
    height: imgSize,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't want to use SafeArea View in my app. How can I get screen Layout size?

Comment: There’s the Dimensions module and useWindowsDimensions hook from react native